# how to answer automatically to a script in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu

i wondering if there is any way to answer automatically a python script, this is the script (i run it with the next command "python manage.py syncdb")

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pydash.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

and when I execute it, this is the output:

```
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): 
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): 
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again):
```

I know bash scripting but I am not good with python, so I am looking for an answer to this question automatically when I run the python script.

For information, this script comes from https://github.com/k3oni/pydash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you understand bash scripting, perhaps this bash command line would work for you.

```
{
    echo yes
    echo bobby-tables
    echo bobby@example.com
    echo "correct horse battery staple"
    echo "correct horse battery staple"
} | python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i'm not sure that the command above is correct at all, or yes ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: ./script.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./script.sh: line 9: ` } | python /var/www/pydash/manage.py syncdb'

Comment: Don't include the word "BASH$" in your script. I meant it only to indicate the shell prompt. I'll also delete it from my example.

Comment: ok, sorry my bad, it almost works, only i have a issue, it hang when python script ask for email address , the hang is here : You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Password: Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): Username (leave blank to use 'root'): Email address:

Comment: Sounds like you need to adjust the `echo` commands to match what the script actually asks.